# ¿Cómo pasar de página para hacer scraping a Google?

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando hacer *Web Scraping* a Google por *hobby*, pero tengo un pequeño problema, y es que no soy capaz de pasar a la página siguiente de resultados, ya que me devuelve siempre la  misma URL.

```
//Este es un ejemplo de mi código:
```

Comment: considera que Google tiene N páginas siguientes, verifica si funciona con 10, 100

Answer (score 0):

Considera al final de los parámetros la búsqueda y el número donde deseas que empiece la búsqueda, por ejemplo:

```
#q=abogados&start=10
```

Donde

- `q=abogados` es la o las palabras buscadas.
- `start=10` es el número donde deseas que inicie la búsqueda de resultados, por ejemplo, `10` corresponde que buscará a partir del resultado 10, lo cual se traduce a la página 2, `20` corresponde a la página 3, y así sucesivamente.

Página 1 - [#q=abogados&start=0](https://www.google.es/search?q=abogados&oq=abogados&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i65j0l4.1776j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=abogados&start=0)

Página 2 - [#q=abogados&start=10](https://www.google.es/search?q=abogados&oq=abogados&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i65j0l4.1776j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=abogados&start=10)

Página 3 - [#q=abogados&start=20](https://www.google.es/search?q=abogados&oq=abogados&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i65j0l4.1776j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=abogados&start=20)

Dependiendo del texto buscado considera que en algunos casos habrá páginas de búsqueda, entonces solo será que valides los resultados obtenidos.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero ya intente incrementar ese valor en 10 con una variable, pero siempre me  devuelve #q=abogados&start=10.  Eso funciona si lo modificas en el buscador pero no desde el código de c#.